# XSLT 2 group and sum values

Tags: xslt, sum, grouping, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to use XSLT 2.0 to sum all individual sales peoples [VOL] for a product [Widgets] for each Year/YearQtr, grouped by their salesteam, department. There could be multiple product types, I've left it as just one type here to try and simplify the code.

1. I've managed to use a for-each to get the list of YearQtr values in a particular Year, but I couldn't work out how to get a distinct list of all Year and YearQtr elements that appear as a child of SalesPerson/Performance.
2. I've tried currentgroup(), but cant see how to specify the grouping so that I would get only the sum at department level, rather than for each SalesPerson.

The XML I'm working with is:

```
<salesteam id="Team1">
    <department id="dept1">
        <salespeople>
            <salesperson id="98765">
                <performance>
                    <year id="2013">
                        <yearqtr id="1">
                            <yearMonth id="1">
                                <products>
                                    <widgets>
                                        <vol>5</vol>
                                        <val>50000</val>
                                    </widgets>
                                </products>
                            </yearMonth>
                            <yearMonth id="2">
                                <products>
                                    <widgets>
                                        <vol>10</vol>
                                        <val>100000</val>
                                    </widgets>
                                </products>
                            </yearMonth>
                            <yearMonth id="3">
                                <products>
                                    <widgets>
                                        <vol>15</vol>
                                        <val>150000</val>
                                    </widgets>
                                </products>
                            </yearMonth>
                        </yearqtr>
                        <yearqtr id="2">
                            <yearMonth id="4">
                                <products>
                                    <widgets>
                                        <vol>20</vol>
                                        <val>200000</val>
                                    </widgets>
                                </products>
                            </yearMonth>
                            <yearMonth id="5">
                                <products>
                                    <widgets>
                                        <vol>25</vol>
                                        <val>250000</val>
                                    </widgets>
                                </products>
                            </yearMonth>
                            <yearMonth id="6">
                                <products>
                                    <widgets>
                                        <vol>30</vol>
                                        <val>300000</val>
                                    </widgets>
                                </products>
                            </yearMonth>
                        </yearqtr>
                    </year>
                </performance>
            </salesperson>
            <salesperson id="12345">
                <performance>
                    <year id="2013">
                        <yearqtr id="1">
                            <yearMonth id="1">
                                <products>
                                    <widgets>
                                        <vol>5</vol>
                                        <val>50000</val>
                                    </widgets>
                                </products>
                            </yearMonth>
                            <yearMonth id="2">
                                <products>
                                    <widgets>
                                        <vol>10</vol>
                                        <val>100000</val>
                                    </widgets>
                                </products>
                            </yearMonth>
                            <yearMonth id="3">
                                <products>
                                    <widgets>
                                        <vol>15</vol>
                                        <val>150000</val>
                                    </widgets>
                                </products>
                            </yearMonth>
                        </yearqtr>
                        <yearqtr id="2">
                            <yearMonth id="4">
                                <products>
                                    <widgets>
                                        <vol>20</vol>
                                        <val>200000</val>
                                    </widgets>
                                </products>
                            </yearMonth>
                            <yearMonth id="5">
                                <products>
                                    <widgets>
                                        <vol>25</vol>
                                        <val>250000</val>
                                    </widgets>
                                </products>
                            </yearMonth>
                            <yearMonth id="6">
                                <products>
                                    <widgets>
                                        <vol>30</vol>
                                        <val>300000</val>
                                    </widgets>
                                </products>
                            </yearMonth>
                        </yearqtr>
                    </year>
                </performance>
            </salesperson>
        </salespeople>
    </department>
</salesteam>
```

What I'd like to achieve is

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>2013Q1</th>
<th>2013Q2</th>
<th>2013Q3</th>
<th>2013Q4</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>30</td>
<td>75</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand why all of your `yearqtr`s have the ID 1, when half of them are `Q2`. Is that a mistake? Your example output also doesn't seem to demonstrate how you want to represent separate salespeople.

Comment: Hi, yes. i'd just copied pasted to make the examples, sorry. I would expect the yearmonth id for yearqtr=1 to be 1, 2 or 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need to use grouping here? If you can safely assume there are always 4 quarters in a year, you can just have a sum statement to sum all the widget volumes for a given quarter, and year, like so (where $year is a parameter holding the year, and $qtr holding the quarter)

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(//year[@id=$year]/yearqtr[@id=$qtr]/yearMonth/products/widgets/vol)" />
```

You could just put this in a named template, with **qtr** as a parameter, and call it four times

```
<xsl:call-template name="sum"><xsl:with-param name="qtr" select="1" /></xsl:call-template>
<xsl:call-template name="sum"><xsl:with-param name="qtr" select="2" /></xsl:call-template>
<xsl:call-template name="sum"><xsl:with-param name="qtr" select="3" /></xsl:call-template>
<xsl:call-template name="sum"><xsl:with-param name="qtr" select="4" /></xsl:call-template>
```

It might be slightly cleaner, and more efficient to use a key to look up the widgets for a given year and quarter though.

```
<xsl:key name="quarters" match="yearqtr" use="concat(../@id, '|', @id)"/>
```

Then your sum becomes this

```
<xsl:value-of 
     select="sum(key('quarters', concat($year, '|', $qtr))/yearMonth/products/widgets/vol)"/>
```

Here is the full XSLT in this case:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:key name="quarters" match="yearqtr" use="concat(../@id, '|', @id)"/>

   <xsl:param name="year" select="2013"/>

   <xsl:template match="/*">
      <table>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <th><xsl:value-of select="$year"/>Q1</th>
               <th><xsl:value-of select="$year"/>Q2</th>
               <th><xsl:value-of select="$year"/>Q3</th>
               <th><xsl:value-of select="$year"/>Q4</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <xsl:call-template name="sum"><xsl:with-param name="qtr" select="1" /></xsl:call-template>
               <xsl:call-template name="sum"><xsl:with-param name="qtr" select="2" /></xsl:call-template>
               <xsl:call-template name="sum"><xsl:with-param name="qtr" select="3" /></xsl:call-template>
               <xsl:call-template name="sum"><xsl:with-param name="qtr" select="4" /></xsl:call-template>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="sum">
      <xsl:param name="qtr"/>
      <td>
         <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('quarters', concat($year, '|', $qtr))/yearMonth/products/widgets/vol)"/>
      </td>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you did want to use grouping though, here is how you would do it in XSLT2.0

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:param name="year" select="2013"/>

   <xsl:template match="/*">
      <table>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <xsl:for-each-group select="//year[@id=$year]/yearqtr" group-by="@id">
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="concat($year, 'Q', current-grouping-key())" /></td>
               </xsl:for-each-group>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <xsl:for-each-group select="//year[@id=$year]/yearqtr" group-by="@id">
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/yearMonth/products/widgets/vol)"/></td>
               </xsl:for-each-group>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This would only display the quarters that exist though, so if there no **yearqtr** elements for a quarter 4, for example, only quarters 1 to 3 would be shown.

EDIT: If you had multiple years, then assuming you still wanted them on separate columns, you would do the grouping like so:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="//yearqtr" group-by="concat(../@id, 'Q', @id)">
```

Here is the full XSLT in this case:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/*">
      <table>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <xsl:for-each-group select="//yearqtr" group-by="concat(../@id, 'Q', @id)">
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()" /></td>
               </xsl:for-each-group>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <xsl:for-each-group select="//yearqtr" group-by="concat(../@id, 'Q', @id)">
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/yearMonth/products/widgets/vol)"/></td>
               </xsl:for-each-group>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Tim C, & Thanks. how could i edit this to cope with more than one year? say I had 2012 as well...

Comment: to clarify, it is possible that the performance values could include a prior year and i would want to show both where possible. Would I edit the headings code like so:                                       <!-- language: lang-xml --> <xsl:for-each-group  select="//year/yearqtr" group-by="@id">

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how to cope with multiple years.